# QWidget removed by removeItem in a scene can't be re-added to another scene

Tags: qt, qt5

We have a `QWidget` which is added to the scene by `addWidget`. We would like to keep it showing when switching to different scene. Our approach is to temporarily remove it from the scene by `removeItem` and after switching to another scene, we call `addWidget` to re-add it. However, the 2nd `addWidget` raises an error:

```
QGraphicsProxyWidget::setWidget: cannot embed widget 0x7835ec8; already embedded
```

Error can be reproduced by below code:

```
QWidget *widget = new QWidget;
scene->addWidget(widget);
scene->removeItem(widget->graphicsProxyWidget());
scene->addWidget(widget);
```

Seems that `removeItem` doesn't really remove the embedded status. Anybody know what's happening here? Or is there any other good approach to meet our requirement?

The Qt version is Qt 5.3.2.

Thanks!

Comment: Your code does not compile for me. `removeItem` takes a `QGraphicsItem`, not a `QGraphicsProxyWidget`.

Comment: You need to add `#include <QGraphicsProxyWidget>` to pass the compilation. Sorry I didn't clearly mention it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, apparently `removeItem` does not remove the embedded status. Code below checks that embedded status is still there and removes it manually using `setWidget`.

I would recommend that you report a [Qt bug](https://bugreports.qt.io/) for that because it really looks like a bug (you can simply point them to this post, I did that in the past).

```
QGraphicsScene* scene = new QGraphicsScene();
QWidget *widget = new QWidget;
// check widget has no proxy:
assert( widget->graphicsProxyWidget() == NULL );
// add the item:
scene->addWidget(widget);
// check widget has a proxy attached:
assert( widget->graphicsProxyWidget() && widget->graphicsProxyWidget()->widget() == widget );
// remove the item:
scene->removeItem(widget->graphicsProxyWidget());

if ( widget->graphicsProxyWidget() && widget->graphicsProxyWidget()->widget() == widget )
{
    // widget still has a proxy attached, is this a Qt bug?

    // manually unset proxy:
    widget->graphicsProxyWidget()->setWidget( NULL );
    // check widget has no proxy:
    assert( widget->graphicsProxyWidget() == NULL );
}
// add the item:
scene->addWidget(widget);
// check widget has a proxy attached:
assert( widget->graphicsProxyWidget() && widget->graphicsProxyWidget()->widget() == widget );
```

Comment: A [Qt bug](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-47388) has been reported. The workaround of this is  to manually call `setWidget(NULL)` after the `remoteItem`, just like your code does. Thanks!